# For loop retrieves same mysql row

Tags: php, mysql

I’m trying to retrieve the first 4 entries with a for loop, but it seems to repeat 1 entry 4 times.

This is my code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM activiteiten");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  for ($result = 1; $result <= 4; $result++) {
    echo "<div class='agenda_item' style='background-color:#F39'>";
    echo "<img src='images/soosavond_small.jpg'  class='soospict_small' />";
    echo "<div class='agenda_content'>";
    echo "<p class='datum'>" . $row['datum'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p class='onderwerp'>" . $row['naam_activiteit'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p class='details'>" . $row['beschrijving'] . "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<a href='#'' class='pijlklein'>MEER INFO</a>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: remove the for loop and change your mysql query

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a **for** loop. I've modified code, to retrive only first 4 items. 
Look at the cahnged query **LIMIT 4**.

```
<?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM activiteiten LIMIT 4");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "<div class='agenda_item' style='background-color:#F39'>";
          echo "<img src='images/soosavond_small.jpg'  class='soospict_small' />";
          echo "<div class='agenda_content'>";
          echo "<p class='datum'>" . $row['datum'] . "</p>";
          echo "<p class='onderwerp'>" . $row['naam_activiteit'] . "</p>";
          echo "<p class='details'>" . $row['beschrijving'] . "</p>";
          echo "</div>";
          echo "<a href='#'' class='pijlklein'>MEER INFO</a>";
          echo "</div>";
      }
        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

Comment: Yes that's what I used to have, but that retrieves all rows, I only need the first 4

Comment: @user3560947 Hah ok, i'll modify my answer. Please come back in a min.

Answer (score 0):

You have a for loop inside the while loop. You can remove the for loop and use `LIMIT` from MySQL (which is better as fetching all entries by PHP (better performance), if you need only the first 4 entries):

```
SELECT * FROM activiteiten LIMIT 4
```

---

If you still want to do it with php:

```
$results = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) && $results < 4) {
    echo "<div class='agenda_item' style='background-color:#F39'>";
    ...
    $results++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code—as presented—mixes things up in ways that behave the way you see. The `for` loop is not needed. And you should set a `LIMIT` in your MySQL query like this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM activiteiten LIMIT 0,4");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<div class='agenda_item' style='background-color:#F39'>";
  echo "<img src='images/soosavond_small.jpg'  class='soospict_small' />";
  echo "<div class='agenda_content'>";
  echo "<p class='datum'>" . $row['datum'] . "</p>";
  echo "<p class='onderwerp'>" . $row['naam_activiteit'] . "</p>";
  echo "<p class='details'>" . $row['beschrijving'] . "</p>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<a href='#'' class='pijlklein'>MEER INFO</a>";
  echo "</div>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

The problem with your original code is mixing `for` with `while` ends up in the scenario you showed as explained in the PHP manual entry for [`while`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php):

> The meaning of a while statement is simple. It tells PHP to execute
>   the nested statement(s) repeatedly, as long as the while expression
>   evaluates to TRUE.

So you have a `while` iterating over the results, but then you also have `for` loop nested in there.  100% unnecessary.

The way I adjusted it is to just removed that `for` loop, but also add `LIMIT 0,4` to the MySQL query.  That basically tells MySQL to fetch 4 rows beginning from the first row which is referred to as `0`.